# Pop-up modal being cut off at top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

[Here is a live demo of the modal](https://cdn.rawgit.com/Twinbird24/tbk-popup/8fb4e760/index.html) (it should open after a few seconds. UPDATE: this link now shows the finished version).

[Here is the GitHub repo with all the files.](https://github.com/Twinbird24/tbk-popup) (UPDATE: this link now shows the finished version).

When I scroll up, the top part of the pop-up is cut off but I can't scroll up to see it, despite having `overflow-y: scroll;` on the pop-up container.

This problem happens (in case you can't see it in the demo) on smaller resolution screens ([see here](https://s20.postimg.org/gkj91brx9/scroll_top1.jpg)) or when the screen width is contracted ([see here](https://s20.postimg.org/yom9lyplp/scroll_top2.jpg)).

Comment: Try set `#pop-up {top: 100%;}`. Is that what you want?

Comment: It didn't fix the issue, sorry :(

Comment: Well, seems to work on demo. Maybe I'm not quite understand what you want.

Comment: I added `#pop-up {top: 100%;}` on demo as well (via chrome dev tools) and it doesn't work. I tried it locally as well. How are you getting it to work?

Comment: Same, I made the changes via dev tools, and tried on both safari and chrome. With cache off.

Comment: @Attila Hi! How did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Yuriy It's been a while since I've looked at this code, but I've updated the links in the question to point to the finished versions. The Accepted answer is what worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend the following changes to the CSS:

- Set `overflow: hidden` on `body` when the popup is open. That will stop the annoying scrolling of the body when trying to scroll the popup.
- Remove the `translate` on `#popup`
- Change the `margin` to `auto`
- Change the `top` and `left` to `0`
- Add `right` and `bottom` and set to `0`

The last items will automatically center the popup content in the window and you will be able to scroll within the popup container div (this works because the position is set to `absolute`).

Also might want to set `background-color: #fff` on `#top-section` so that if the window is short you can still see the text otherwise it ends up with black text on the dark transparent background.

Comment: Setting overflow to hidden on body was nice, but I did the other steps and it didn't help :(

Comment: Huh, I set this up over here and it looks right to me, am I missing something? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpoRyj

Comment: I also tested it via browser dev tool. It works as @Pango described. Might not be what Attila expecting though.

Comment: I tried again locally, it didn't work. I tried to apply the changes as well on the live demo (via chrome dev tools) and it doesn't work either - one thing it does it push the bottom white cube up into the form, and the top is still cut off on a smaller width. I'm starting to wonder if other users who are providing answers are seeing different results because of OS/ browser differences/ native screen resolutions/ whatever else may be different between us lol

Comment: Does it not look like you are expecting in the code pen link? What browser and OS are you using? I am on Mac Chrome. To fix the bottom square, you can move the `bottom-cube` div inside of `bottom-section` and then use some of the same tricks. Set `bottom-section` position to `relative` and then update the styles on `bottom-cube`:
`bottom: -35px; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto;`. Left and right 0 with margin auto to center it, and top -25px to place it overlapping on the outside like in your demo. Updated: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpoRyj

Comment: I don't know wtf I've been doing before, but I went through it again, and it looks like how you have it in the codepen now, I really do apologize for the confusion. Thank you very much though for the answer! One last thing I need to figure out now is how to prevent the top cube from being cut off (i.e. the #top-cub).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I'm a little bit late to reply, but setting the css property of the modal itself to:

```
max-height: 100%;
```

May repair this issue.

Answer (score -1):

For me removing `display: flex;` did the trick