# Top part of pop-up modal cuts off screen when screen is reduced in size

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

The top part of my modal gets cut off the screen when the screen is reduced (it disappears under the bookmarks and address bar) . I have tried the solution at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775664/pop-up-modal-being-cut-off-at-top-of-page) (to set top and bottom to 0) but not working for me.

My css is as follows:

```
/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 50%;
padding: 0px 20px 15px;
background: #fff;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Regards, Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your content is too large for the window? If that's right, then set `max-height: 100vh;` and the modal won't grow beyond the window's height, whilst your code above should continue to center it.